# Как парсить динамическое содержание страницы

Tags: java, парсер

Требуется пропарсить youtube стрим на кол-во смотрящих стрим, это значение динамическое и оно обновляется. Jsoup и selerium не подходят. Подскажите подходящее решение.

Comment: selenium подходит. также можете попробовать phantomjs.

Comment: Мне selenium не подходит, phantomjs для javascript у меня java

Comment: чем не подходит? у phantomjs и для java есть драйвер.